# Permissions.revoke() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, permissions, geolocation, navigator

I'm working on a button to revoke browser location permissions, during my search I found that "Permissions.revoke()" works, but when reviewing the documentation I find that it is deprecated. I've been searching and can't find anything similar, what could I use to do the same thing?

This is the line i'm using:

```
function toggleLocation() {
  navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.state === 'granted') {
      navigator.permissions.revoke({ name: 'geolocation' });
      $('#toggle_location').html('Turn location on');
    } else if (result.state === 'prompt') {
      navigator.permissions.request({ name: 'geolocation' });
      $('#toggle_location').html('Turn location off');
    } else if (result.state === 'denied') {
      navigator.permissions.request({ name: 'geolocation' });
      $('#toggle_location').html('Turn location off');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Permissions.revoke()

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some
> browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from
> the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or
> may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and
> update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the
> bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature
> may cease to work at any time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/revoke

Comment: Is there any alternative to this ?